# What did Mr. Standall burn?

Tags: plot-explanation, 13-reasons-why

In the last episode of 13 reasons why (season 3),

> in the scene after Mr. Standall embraced Alex saying he loved him, we see him secretly burning someone's clothes, including a plaid
>  shirt, jeans and probably a jacket.

Who's were those?

> Were they the one Alex was wearing when he threw Bryce off the bridge?

If yes, how did Mr.Standall know or remember specifically what clothes his son was wearing that day? Also, I doubt there was any kind of evidence like blood on them, and even if it was, it would've been washed by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Heavy.com](https://heavy.com/entertainment/2019/08/13-reasons-why-season-3-alex-dad-burning/) tried to dig that for you:

> During the scene, it looked like Bill was burning a pair of jeans, a shirt, a jacket, and a blue flannel top.
>
> The flannel top is especially obvious in the scene where it’s burning.
>
> And it’s this flannel top that holds the clue about what Bill’s burning. Some fans think it’s Monty’s top since he was wearing a flannel top on the night that Bryce died. But it’s actually more likely to be Alex’s shirt. Check out what Alex was wearing the night that Bryce died.

Also when he said he wished it was his head, not Alex:

> I wished that bullet was in my head, not yours. You understand?

which shows he can do anything to protect him even a bullet to his head. Also, he is in the police department so we can guess he is good with paying attention to details, especially on a big day.

Also, sometimes parents are like that, my mom used to remember what I wore weeks back when even I forget sometimes.

But now your major question, why he burned it?

Most probably to protect Alex and indicating he knows the truth. We can't be sure that his cloth had no blood on them, Bruce was wounded when he was throwing him and  Standall being a cop can't take chances.

Comment: But couldn't the blood be simply washed off?

Comment: @BellaSwan by bleach, yes but it will ruin the colour of the cloth :P and I am sure they can afford losing one pair of cloth on the salary of a cop

Comment: And having an issue of nose bleed I know it's not easy removing a blood stain from cloths, white is easy as bleach and cloth whitener, etc can work but color cloths are worse if the stain is older. And I guess only bleach can save it from ultraviolet light detection but will dig about ti later.